# Maintaining column order when adding two dataframes with similar formats

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two dataframes with similar formats. Both have 3 indexes/headers. Most of the headers are the same but df2 has a few additional ones. When I add them up the order of the headers gets mixed up. I would like to maintain the order of df1. Any ideas?

```
Global = pd.read_excel('Mickey Mouse_Clean2.xlsx',header=[0,1,2,3],index_col=[0,1],sheet_name = 'Global')
Oslav = pd.read_excel('Mickey Mouse_Clean2.xlsx',header=[0,1,2,3],index_col=[0,1],sheet_name = 'Country XYZ')

Oslav = Oslav.replace(to_replace=1,value=10)
Oslav = Oslav.replace(to_replace=-1,value=-2)

df = Global.add(Oslav,fill_value=0)
```

**Example of df Format**

```
                 HeaderA      |        Header2     |        Header3      |
           xxx1|xxx2|xxx3|xxx4||xxx1|xxx2|xxx3|xxx4||xxx1|xxx2|xxx3|xxx4 |
ColX|ColY |ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD||ColD|ColE|ColF|ColG||ColH|ColI|ColJ|ColDK|
1   | ds  | 1  |    |+1  |-1  | .......................................
2   | dh  |  ..........................................................
3   | ge  |  ..........................................................
4   | ew  |  ..........................................................
5   | er  |  ..........................................................
```

Comment: Show us example dataframes so we have a [mcve]. We can't read your Excel files. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51899921/edit), please do not include links or images, just text.

Comment: Note that you can also post sample dataframes that show the same behavior, if it wouldn't be practical to post the actual files.

Comment: If you simply want to re-order the columns consider using `df.reindex()`

Comment: I would like to order based on column header 0 and column header 3. Could I use `df.reindex()` for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[Global.columns+list(set(Oslav.columns)-set(Global.columns))].copy()
```

or

```
df = df[Global.columns+[col for col in Oslav.columns if not col in Global.columns]].copy()
```

(The second option should preserve the order of `Oslav` columns as well, if you care about that.)

or

```
df = df.reindex(columns=Global.columns+list(set(Oslav.columns)-set(Global.columns)))
```

If you don't want to keep the columns that are in `Oslav`, but not in `Global`, you can do

```
df = df[Global.columns].copy()
```

Note that without `.copy()`, you're getting a view of the previous dataframe, rather than a dataframe in its own right.

Comment: I now get the error: TypeError: cannot perform __add__ with this index type: MultiIndex

Comment: Were you not getting that error before? I intended my answer to be code for you to run after performing the `add`, so I don't see how it could cause an error in a previous statement.

Comment: I did not get that error before. I assume this is because my df have multiple headers? If I run `df = df[Global.columns].copy()` I get df with only the Global headers. Once I start adding and subtracting to get both Global + Oslav I get the above error. Could that be because of the multiple headers?

Comment: Added an example of how the dfs look